# Android Studio Layout not being set

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-studio

I'm writing a weather app and want to display hourly forecasts in a horizontalscrollview. I get the data from some json objects/ arrays which I get from a weather class I created, which is invoked using asynctask. The horizontal scroll view has a linear layout (horizontal) since it can only have one child, that then contains several vertical linear layouts with two textview and an imageview. This way the single row contains columns and each column has an hour, temperature, and icon stacked together, all of which I want to set programmatically. Everything looks fine and builds fine, but when I run the app on a galaxy tab s, only the the activity_main.xml layout seems to be invoked, as if it never implements my horizontal scroll view layout.

Here's my onCreate() of MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

        HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsvView);
        LinearLayout linLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLay);


        //linlay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        //linlay.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,50dp, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       // hsv.addView(linlay);

        int viewCount = 10;

        final LinearLayout[] childLayout = new LinearLayout[viewCount];
        final TextView[] hourText = new TextView[viewCount];
        final TextView[] tempText = new TextView[viewCount];
        final ImageView[] iconView = new ImageView[viewCount];


        for(int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {

            childLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
            childLayout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            //childLayout[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            hourText[i] = new TextView(this);
            tempText[i] = new TextView(this);
            iconView[i] = new ImageView(this);

            childLayout[i].addView(hourText[i]);
            childLayout[i].addView(tempText[i]);
            childLayout[i].addView(iconView[i]);

            linLay.addView(childLayout[i]);


        }

        //put into separate class

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setText("Get Weather");



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //may want to listen for good network connection response first

                WeatherTask WunWeather = new WeatherTask(context, childLayout,hourText,tempText,iconView, button);
                WunWeather.execute();
            }


        });

    }

}
```

My activity_main.xml is the standard one that gets created with every project. I deleted the floating action button and replaced the standard include @layout/content_main with @layout/horizontal_scroll.

Here's my horizontal_scroll.xml layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/button_text"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/hsvView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linLay">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my WeatherTask to set all of these views from the collected data for all of this on another thread. I do know that the json data is being retrieved correctly.:

```
    public class WeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    LinearLayout[] child;
    TextView[] hoursView;
    String[] hoursData = new String[10];
    TextView[] tempsView;
    String[] tempsData = new String[10];
    ImageView[] iconsView;
    //String[] iconsUrl = new String[10];
    Bitmap[] iconsBit = new Bitmap[10];

    Button button;
    Context context;

    JSONObject json;
    JSONArray hourly;

    //Bitmap icon = null;

    String AM_PM = "";

    /*
    WeatherTast(Textview[] text, ImageView[] icons, Button button) {

    }
     */
    WeatherTask(Context context, LinearLayout[] child, TextView[] hours, TextView[] temps, ImageView[] icons, Button button) {
        this.context = context;
        this.child = child;
        this.hoursView = hours;
        this.tempsView = temps;
        this.iconsView = icons;
        this.button = button;
    }

    //after onpreexecute() method
    //passes result to onpostexecute()
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("AsyncTask","got to doInBackground");
        //goes to onpostexecute()
        //need eventually call on gps class to get lat/lon from here
        GetWeather weather = new GetWeather(40.693,-89.590);
        json = weather.jsonWeather(); //organized by hour
        Log.d("AsyncTask", String.valueOf(json));
        //send json up to database

        try {
            //hourly = json.getJSONArray("Hourly Forecast");
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                JSONObject tempHour = json.getJSONArray("Hourly Forecast").getJSONObject(i);
                hoursData[i] = tempHour.getString("Hour"); //get hour
                tempsData[i] = tempHour.getString("Hour Temp");

                iconsBit[i] = null;
                InputStream in = new URL(tempHour.getString("Icon")).openStream();
                iconsBit[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                //may want to save all images locally
            }



        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        int minutes = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int hours = time.get(Calendar.HOUR);

        if (time.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 1) {
            AM_PM = "PM";
        } else {AM_PM = "AM";}
        //Integer hour = currentTime.HOUR;
        //Integer min = currentTime.MINUTE;

        return null;
    }
    //first method called in asynctask with .execute() in main ui thread
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //may not want to clear out latest data just in case a network connection exception is thrown
        button.setText("Getting weather");
        Log.d("AsyncTask", "got to preexecute");
        // textView.setText("");
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

        //return s;
    }

    //after finishing job, publishes result to UI thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        //super.onPostExecute(j);
        //button says "weather updated @timestamp
        //imageView downloads icon image last
        //textView shows current temp
        Log.d("AsyncTask","got to onpostExecute");

        try {
            //j.getString("Temperature");
            Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                hoursView[i].setText(hoursData[i]);
                tempsView[i].setText("Temperature: " + tempsData[i] + "\u2109");
                iconsView[i].setImageBitmap(iconsBit[i]);
            }
            button.setText("Weather Updated at " + time.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                    + " " + AM_PM);

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }

    }

}
```

As you can tell, I'm very new to apps. My logcat doesn't have any errors, but none of the log.d statements in my WeatherTask is being displayed. Thanks for any help. I'm using API 23 on Windows x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you don't have content in the layout in the very beginning and the provided layout parameters like wrap_content rely on the content to size the views properly. The views will be shown before the user clicks the button (since the button is a view itself).

The first stage of showing the views is measuring. At this point the measuring process will assign width and height = 0 to every empty linear layout(or with children with sizes 0), empty text view and empty image view which was set to wrap_content and the whole layout becomes invisible. You can read more about showing views [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

When you later fill the text views and the image views they are already being shown and since they are with a size 0, you cannot actually see the content. To redraw the views from scratch, you need to call `requestLayout()`, then android should measure them, set up the layout and finally draw the views. To achieve that, at the end of `onPostExecute()` you can add the following code:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = context.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
parentLayout.requestLayout();
```

This should update the views and show them correctly.

Notice that we don't call `invalidate()` instead, because it just does the final step - drawing the view.

You may want to include the data when you are creating the activity, so the user never sees a blank space, but if you do that, note that because of the asynchronous task measuring can happen before it finishes and you will have to use `requestLayout()` again.

Comment: I thought it may have something to do with that. I put in your two lines to no avail. My logcat tags from my asynctask aren't even showing up in the logcat, as if my app never even makes it that far. Do I need to requestLayout() at all in my MainActivity? And do I also need to do a requestLayout for each of my views and layouts?